# Вопрос про сохранение фото

Tags: java, android

Данная программа сохраняет полученные с камеры фото в папку `Pictures/Faces` , давая название каждому из них по принципу, `"face_" + n + ".jpg"` , где n - переменная, значение которой было получено из файла schet.dat (этот файл тоже создается в начале. Значения в нем увеличиваются на 1 при каждом сохранении фотографии). У меня получилось сохранять сделанные фото под нужными мне именами, но есть одна проблема. Например, пользователь сделал первые три фото, они сохранились как face_1.jpg, face_2.jpg и face_3.jpg. Все нормально, но когда пользователь удаляет все снимки из `Pictures/Faces` , Они по прежнему продолжают сохраняться как face_4.jpg, face_5.jpg, face_6.jpg и т. д. 
Так вот. Я поставил условие, проверяющее является ли папка Faces пустой, но это не помогает. Пожалуйста помогите.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements ImgPath
{

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        imagesFolder.mkdir();

        Button buttonCheck = (Button)findViewById(R.id.mainButton);
        buttonCheck.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    MyappDir.mkdir();
                    File schet = new File(MyappDir, "schet.dat");
                    if(imagesFolder == null | schet == null){ 
                        DataOutputStream out = null; 
                        try { 
                            Integer n = Integer.valueOf(1);
                            out = new DataOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(schet));
                            out.writeInt(n.intValue()); 
                            out.close();
                            File image = new File(imagesFolder, "face_" + n + ".jpg");
                            Uri uriSavedImage = Uri.fromFile(image);
                            cameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, uriSavedImage);
                            startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, 1112);
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace(); 
                        } 
                    } else {
                        Integer n = 0;
                        DataInputStream in = null; 
                        try { 
                            in = new DataInputStream(new FileInputStream(schet)); 
                            n = Integer.valueOf(in.readInt());
                            in.close();
                            n++;
                            File image = new File(imagesFolder, "face_" + n + ".jpg");
                            Uri uriSavedImage = Uri.fromFile(image);
                            cameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, uriSavedImage);
                            startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, 1112);
                        } catch (Exception e) { 
                            e.printStackTrace();  
                        }
                        DataOutputStream out = null; 
                        try { 
                            out = new DataOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(schet));
                            out.writeInt(n.intValue()); 
                            out.close();
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace(); 
                        } 
                    }
                }
        });
    }

    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Result.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

Comment: Где у вас `imagesFolder` объявлена?

Comment: В интерфейсе. Вот она `File imagesFolder = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES + "/Faces/");`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас условие `if(imagesFolder == null | schet == null)` проверяет наличие папки только и есть ли файл **schet.dat**. То есть, сработает только 1 раз.

Вам надо там ещё проверку делать на количество элементов в папке:

```
if(imagesFolder == null || imagesFolder.listFiles().length == 0 || schet == null){ 
  // 
}
```

Comment: Спасибо! Я то гуглил, вставлял `imagesFolder.lenght() == 0` , не прокатывало. А сейчас работает. Спасибо

Comment: @Никитоs да не за что. `imagesFolder.listFiles()` - обычный массив, а у них надо брать `length`. У списков/хешей надо брать `size()`.